# iOS only rotate one of the childviewcontrollers

Tags: ios, swift, xamarin, uiviewcontroller

Is it possible to only rotate one of the child vc?

The xamarin code (it's pretty much the same as swift)

```
mainVC.addChildViewController(childVC_A);
mainVC.addChildViewController(childVC_B);
mainVC.addSubView(childVC_A.View);
mainVC.addSubView(childVC_B.View);
```

the `mainVC` has `shouldAutorotate` to be true and `GetSupportedInterfaceOrientations` to return all orientation;

I only want `childVC_A` to autorotate to landscape mode and `childVC_B` to always remain in portrait mode.

`childVC_A` has `shouldAutorotate` to be `true` and `GetSupportedInterfaceOrientations` to return all orientations;

`childVC_B` has `shouldAutorotate` to be `false` and `GetSupportedInterfaceOrientations` to return only portrait;

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak to the specifics of Xamarin, but normally it is not possible to use the system rotation mechanism to rotate part of the screen and not another part (it is also difficult to do something like rotate only one of the tabs of a `UITabController` effectively).  You're more or less stuck hooking into the accelerometer (`CoreLocation`) and implementing that partial rotation on your own.

Comment: is there a way to force a subview/vc to layout as if it was rotated to landscape?

Comment: @zaftcoAgeiha You can set the `transform` property of the view controller's view to apply a rotation, yes.  You can read about that property in [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/transform), of course.